# #VALUE error in Excel 2010 RegExp

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement Regular Expressions in Excel 2010 on a mac, but with any formulas and data all I get is #VALUE errors

Here is my implementation in a module:

```
Function RegExp1(ReplaceIn, ReplaceWhat As String, _
  ReplaceWith As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False)

    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    re.Pattern = ReplaceWhat
    re.Global = True

    RegExp1 = re.Replace(ReplaceIn, ReplaceWith)
End Function
```

And then in the cell I try:

```
=RegExp1(D2,"(PR2001\.)(\d)","$100$2")
```

All of this is executing on cells similar to:

```
PR2001.1
PR2001.2
PR2001.3
```

etc... I am trying to add zeros in between the last digit and period to format for easier sorting. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So far as i know VBScript is not available on Mac so this simply won't work.  FWIW your code and example work on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel X does not support VBScript, so you will not be able to do this. The functon works and the expression is fine, btw.

What I can suggest to you is to write a function using InStrRev (actually this is a good solution even if you could use regexp).

```
Function AddZeros(ByVal text As String) As String

Dim lastPeriod As Long
lastPeriod = InStrRev(text, ".")

If lastPeriod <> 0 Then
    AddZeros = Left$(text, lastPeriod) & ("00" & Mid$(text, lastPeriod + 1))
Else
    AddZeros = text
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, cant believe X doesn't support regEx. Brutal.